# JavaFX 8 Problems with -fx-background css style selector

Tags: css, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a custom button control. I created MyButton class extends from Control as shown below

```
public class MyButton extends Control {
    private StringProperty textProperty=null;

    public MyButton() {
        this("Button");
    }

    public MyButton(String text) {
        setSkin(new MyButtonSkin(this));
        setText(text);
    }

    public final StringProperty textProperty() {
        if(textProperty==null) {
            textProperty=new SimpleStringProperty();
        }
        return textProperty;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }
}
```

As you can see at line 9, I use a skin named MyButtonSkin that I show you soon

```
public class MyButtonSkin extends SkinBase<MyButton>{
    private final Paint DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR=Color.GRAY;

    private Background background;

    private Label label;

    public MyButtonSkin(MyButton control) {
        super(control);
        label=new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(control.textProperty());


        getChildren().add(label);

        initGraphics();
        initListeners();
    }

    private void initGraphics() {
        background=new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR, new CornerRadii(20), new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0)));
        getSkinnable().setBackground(background);
    }

    private void initListeners() {
        getSkinnable().layoutBoundsProperty().addListener(obs-> {
            Bounds b=getSkinnable().layoutBoundsProperty().get();
            label.resizeRelocate(
                    b.getMinX(), b.getMinY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
        });

        //handler for mouse pressed and released are omitted because
        // I think they are not important in order to solve my problem

    }

    protected double computePrefWidth(double height, 
            double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
        return label.prefWidth(height);
    }
}
```

This is how the button looks like

[image: pure button]

Now, If I add a style in scene builder like

```
-fx-background-color: yellow
```

It looks like that

[image: button with -fx-background-color: yellow style]

The problem I'm facing off is why -fx-background-color style selector change corner radii and insets of the background too? Same thing if I use -fx-background-radius only, it replace also the color and the insets at their default value.
Shouldn't -fx-background-color selector only change background color (or fill, as javafx call)? Same for -fx-background-radius for corner radii and -fx-background-insets for insets?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work as you expect.  I advise defining the background in a CSS stylesheet associated with your control rather than in the initGraphics method.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question: it might be better to size and locate your label inside an overridden layoutChildren method with a layoutInArea call rather than via a layout bounds listener.   Or perhaps subclassing LabeledSkinBase or ButtonSkin might be more appropriate than the plain SkinBase.

Comment: I tried to define the background in a CSS file but if I redistribute my control and by scene builder I override the style as I shown in the post above I've the unwanted behavior.

Comment: I don't want sublass LabeledSkinBase, ButtonSkin or whatever skin of the javafx private api. Because I experimented with them and arised some other strange behaviors.

Comment: The other skin classes become [public API in Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/253).  But I understand that it does not always make sense to use them and sometimes it can be beneficial to work from basics like SkinBase rather than the more specialized subclasses.

Comment: Thank you for comments. However I would like to unterstand if the behavior I showed in the post above is a correct behavior or is a bug.